# Getting autocomplete with zsh and justfile (homebrew)

Tags: homebrew, zsh, oh-my-zsh, just

I'm using ZSH, oh-my-zsh, and just. If I'm in the root of my directory that contains a justfile, type `just`, and then press tab, it doesn't autocomplete.

But if I `exec zsh` in terminal and then do `just <tab>`, it works correctly. How can I fix this? How can I make it so just autocompletes without needing to `exec zsh`?

Note: This question applies to anything installed with home brew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in the `just` [project README](https://github.com/casey/just#shell-completion-scripts). I had searched this many times before and hadn't found the solution. The README must have been recently updated.

Add the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
# Needed for just autocomplete, but will pull in all of brew
# https://github.com/casey/just#shell-completion-scripts
# Init Homebrew, which adds environment variables
eval "$(brew shellenv)"
# Add Homebrew's site-functions to fpath
fpath=($HOMEBREW_PREFIX/share/zsh/site-functions $fpath)

# Needed for autosuggestions (does compinit)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Note: This solution works generically for anything installed with home brew